# Use Response of a wcf request as request in another receive port

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2013

Is there any way to use the response of a wcf service method request as an input for the next request in same orchestration and return the response of the first request as well as the response of the second request as out put in BizTalk?

Eg :

My first request gives a response as "a"

Give this response "a" as request to the 2nd request and gets the response as "b"

Return the response as "a" and "b".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You could either create a map from Response 1 to Request 2, and also create a multiple input message map from Response 1 and Response 2 to your final output message.

If the messages involved don't have any repeating structures, it may be enough to distinguish the fields that you need to be concerned with and just use a ConstructMessage with an XmlDocument, i.e.

```
// construct shape code
varXmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
varXmlDoc.LoadXml("<webSvcRequest2 xmlns=''><ParamB>" + msgWebSvcResp1.ParamA + "</ParamB></webSvcRequest2>");
msgWebSvcReq2 = varXmlDoc;
```

And similar code for producing the final output message.  If you go this route, I'd advice creating some C# utility methods to actually store the strings/message templates.